# Why expanding on left hand side arg is leading to error

Tags: bash

I accidentally wrote next assignment in one of my scripts:
`$X=$(echo 'astring')`
which fails with `=astring: command not found`.
The correct and intended assignment was `X=$(echo 'astring')` which works and sets `X='astring'`.
The question is what happens with the first one? Is `$` trying to execute the result of the right hand side? And if that is so then why is it also incorporating `=` in it? I'm confused.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `echo X` and `echo $X`? Same thing exactly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `$X=$(echo 'astring')` depends on the contents of `$X`. When it's empty (which it probably was), it expands to an empty string, and the remaining string is interpreted as a command

```
$X=$(echo 'astring')
  =astring
```

If `$X` contains something, e.g. "astring", the string is expanded to

```
astring=astring
```

But it doesn't set the `$astring` variable as one might think, because of the order of expansions. Assignments are identified before any expansion happens. So, it's interpreted as a command again

```
astring=astring: command not found
```